# MS ACCESS database control by admin

Tags: database, admin

Actually I am trying to find out , I have a plenty of process updates which needs to be saved in MS Access database in a share drive where the users can only view the documents but the admin should have access to add/delete/modify the document in data base. I thought ms access is good for me since we don't have access to other tools.

Comment: I'm confused; what's your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're using terms should as users, but in the context of "shares" and "ms access", that term is ambiguous. You can have users that are MS Access-specific to that database, or you can have domain users that have access to file shares, and limit your permissions through the domain. Which are you referring to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to control user rights to an Access database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529225/how-to-control-user-rights-to-an-access-database)