# SQL Server Import OLE DB error 0x80040E09

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I just installed SQL Server 2014 and now I'm trying to import an `Access` database. To do the import I use the `SQL Server 2014 Import and Export Data Wizard`. I can go trough all steps of the wizard except the step below, which gives me this error.

[image]

The red underlined text is Dutch the translation for this line is: Cannot read the records. U don't have permission for tblAanmaningHistorie to read the data.
`tblAanmaningHistorie` is the first table in the `Access` database, when I try to import other tables I get the same error.

Data source screen

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Do the import using a login that has permission to use the Access database.

Comment: How can I set the permission? How to give Admin permission to use the Access db?

Comment: the screenshot has a username / password box there...maybe put the credentials there?

Comment: @ewahner the credentials of `Admin` ? I tried that already and that doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529225/how-to-control-user-rights-to-an-access-database

Comment: This doesn't explain which credentials to put in the username / password box.

Comment: That error means that you don' have access to that DB obviously. Whoever is the admin for the DB needs to give you temporary access to that Db or table or just do the import for you.

Comment: I created both DB's the SQL Server and Access db and I'm on an admin account.

Comment: If you try to open the database in Access itself are you prompted for a UserName and Password?

Comment: No I'm not prompted for username/password

Comment: Try this: Open the database in Access, hit [Alt-F11] to open the VBA editor, then hit [Ctrl-G] to open the Immediate Window. Type `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "GRANT SELECT ON tblAanmaningHistorie TO Admin"` and press [Enter]. Then try the import again.