# Force user login after x min of inactivity

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an application which has 1 login form, 1 main dashboard form, 7/8 sub dashboard forms and many other non-main/dashboard forms.

I would like to implement some sort of system, whereby if the user has been inactive for x minutes, that they are asked to login again.

Is there a way to have a global function run continuously that will check every 60 seconds if a login is required? The obvious way is using the `on timer` event. However with so many forms I would have to add the call to each form etc.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Put the timer feature in just one form --- the first form or one which is early in the sequence of open forms.  Hide that form when the user is done with it.  With that form open but hidden, its timer will remain active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is an easy way to do this.

First off, we have to define what "*user has been inactive for x minutes*" really means. There are some options:

1. The **Access application was not the focused window** for x minutes. (Drawback: the user could be idling with the Access application on front, never triggering the focus loss)
2. A certain **form was not focused** for x minutes. (Drawback: You'd have to implement the check routine for each and every form in you application, logging all `GotFocus` and/or `LostFocus` events to verify that at least all x minutes another form was focused. But: A user legitimately working for x minutes with the same form never needing to change its focus will nevertheless trigger the logout.)
3. **No user interaction occurred** (that is, events triggered from button clicks and so on) for x minutes. (Drawback: For each event that you handle you have to add additional code to reset the x-minutes-timer. Also you'll need to introduce new event handlers for the naviagtion (see #2, focus loss) so you don't log off users being active by navigating the forms.)
4. ... other methods that probably won't work better either.

There is no good way to do this without having to cope with a host of new problems.

The better solution would be to set a default idle time in your backend database, assuming it is an active database server and not just another Access database (or even the same database where the forms are in).

In the latter case where you don't have a dedicated database server I would challenge you to rethink why you want a timeout of the login in the first place. Or, to rephrase:

**What is a login good for in an Access-only database?**

Security? There is no way you can prevent a user from accessing all data in your database, independent of them having a login or not. Remember: An Access database is just a file on the filesystem. A user *using* that database has, in fact, already access to everything in that file. There is no such thing as user-level security in Access (not anymore at least; and that's for the best).

You can encrypt the whole database (File --> Info), but you can only specify one password per database, not per user. Again: User-level security cannot be done in Access.

See this answer for more on security of Access databases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/530778/6216216