# How do I control user access and data permissions

Tags: vba, ms-access

Let me preface this with the fact that I don't know much about VBA.  I have created a database that will be split and the front end will be distributed to 14 different project managers.  The database is intended to allow users to enter bi-weekly updates to their projects.  I hope to get some guidance on creating usernames and passwords so that PMs can only access their project data.

I don't mind creating and issuing usernames and passwords to each user, but I am trying to avoid creating 14 copies of the database.  That would make providing updated databases a nightmare.

Hopefully this isn't too basic of a question for this group.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question (edit) e.g environment (company network with active directory?).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to control user rights to an Access database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529225/how-to-control-user-rights-to-an-access-database)

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can control users access, you need to create a user table in your backend database that will hold their firstname, surname, password, and any other user specific data that you might need, e.g. department, access level, etc.
In your front end, you need a login form and you make that the Display Form for your fe (set in the access options menu).  You check the username and password entered matches what is held in your database, and if it's correct, you load the appropriate form, usually a main menu, and show them the appropriate data based on the login they used. You may need to hold the login they used in a TempVar, so you can access it from any form, report, query etc in your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like [LASsie (Light Application Security)](http://www.peterssoftware.com/las.htm) or program a similar solution yourself.

Also, you may enjoy my article [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html).

*(If you don't have an account, browse for the link: Read the full article.)*